# Inserting unix time and special symbol

Tags: mysql

Trying to run this query -

```
INSERT INTO rmedvedeva993@gmail.com  (url,unix) 
    VALUES (@https://youtu.be/xXsuqrhD8pw,@1500152563.66077);
```

after reading about this issue tried wrapping database like this- `rmedvedeva993@gmail.com`

getting an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '://youtu.be/xXsuqrhD8pw,@1500152563.66077)' at line 1

not quite sure what's the issue here,

P.S.: my columns are formated as `char(255)`

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to quote your `strings` (whether `char(xx)`, `varchar(xx)`, or any other type which is represented as a `string`); and, when the names of your tables are not just letters and numbers, you have to quote them with the `backtick` quote: `` ` ``. You most probably don't won't either the `@` symbol.

```
INSERT INTO `rmedvedeva993@gmail.com`  (url,unix) 
   VALUES ('https://youtu.be/xXsuqrhD8pw','1500152563.66077');
```

---

**Side Note**: Is your table really named `rmedvedeva993@gmail.com`? Can you post your table definitions (use [`SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-table.html)).

Comment: Thank you, i had to wrap the table name in ` 
note to anyone who might stumble upon in the future, - there is a difference between ' and `

Answer (score 1):

`@hhttps://youtu.be/xXsuqrhD8pw` and `@1500152563.66077` aren't valid.

Neither is an email address as the name of a table. If you MUST use an email address as a table name, enclose it in backticks. But think long and hard about why you're doing that, then don't do it.

You probably want `VALUES ('https://youtu.be/xXsuqrhD8pw',1500152563.66077);` .

The `@` symbol in MySQL's dialect of structured query language denotes a user-defined variable.  So you could have this:

```
 @url := 'https://youtu.be/xXsuqrhD8pw';
 @ts := 1500152563.66077;
 INSERT INTO table  (url,unix) VALUES  (@url,@ts);
```

Comment: Why would you do it this way? That data can be inlined as joanolo shows.

Comment: I wouldn't do it that way myself. I wrote that so the writer of the question might be able to put together the purpose of the `@` symbol.

Comment: I think the original question mis-interpreted code in an example like yours to think `@url` was how you inserted the text `"url"`.